# How can I sort parts of a string of repeating elements and different values into different arrays based on the element?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, object

I am currently trying to convert the following string into several arrays based on the elements (such as freq, mag, etc." This string was originally in a json format, but using Gson, it was converted into an object of another class I am using, then transformed into a string in order to make sorting easier (for me anyways.) I am looking for either advice on how to transform this into arrays with the string or if there is any other way to prepare multiple arrays that is simpler.

```
[freq: 17.97  mag: 8.22  bw: 0.44  snr: 2.47  med: 3.33, freq: 9.96  mag: 4.06  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.31  med: 1.76, freq: 23.05  mag: 0.92  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.24  med: 0.41, freq: 12.99  mag: 1.07  bw: 0.38  snr: 2.19  med: 0.49, freq: 7.18  mag: 18.54  bw: 0.47  snr: 2.15  med: 8.61]
```

Ideally, I would end up with something as follows:

```
frequencyArray[0] = 17.97
frequencyArray[1] = 9.96
frequencyArray[x] = [x]
```

etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string based on Pattern Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345830/splitting-a-string-based-on-pattern-java)

Comment: Can you change the String? because if so, you can just use `.split()` otherwise I suggest a more complex regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = "freq: 17.97  mag: 8.22  bw: 0.44  snr: 2.47  med: 3.33, freq: 9.96  mag: 4.06  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.31  med: 1.76, freq: 23.05  mag: 0.92  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.24  med: 0.41, freq: 12.99  mag: 1.07  bw: 0.38  snr: 2.19  med: 0.49, freq: 7.18  mag: 18.54  bw: 0.47  snr: 2.15  med: 8.61";

Map<String, List<Float>> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] split = s.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    String a = split[i];
    if (a.contains(":")) {
        String substring = a.substring(0, a.length() - 1);
        if (map.containsKey(substring)) {
            String floatString = split[++i].trim();
            if (floatString.endsWith(",")) {
                floatString = floatString.substring(0, floatString.length() - 1);
            }
            map.get(substring).add(Float.valueOf(floatString));
        } else {
            List<Float> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String floatString = split[++i].trim();
            if (floatString.endsWith(",")) {
                floatString = floatString.substring(0, floatString.length() - 1);
            }
            list.add(Float.valueOf(floatString));
            map.put(substring, list);
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(map);
```

A `Map` of `List` would be better suited for this problem.

Output:

```
{ mag=[8.22, 4.06, 0.92, 1.07, 18.54], 
  bw=[0.44, 0.41, 0.41, 0.38, 0.47], 
  snr=[2.47, 2.31, 2.24, 2.19, 2.15], 
  freq=[17.97, 9.96, 23.05, 12.99, 7.18], 
  med=[3.33, 1.76, 0.41, 0.49, 8.61]
}
```

I have sanitized some of the Strings like removed the extra `","` after some values.

Comment: I believe the commas were to separate rows and are significant

Comment: @user, I believe they are just there so that we can maintain order. I have done that. We have the same output in different data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting it into a map like this

I have assumed your format to be very regular, with 2 spaces separating 2 key-value pairs and commas separating rows of data

```
key1: x.xx  key2: x.xx  key3: x.xx, key1: x.xx  key2: x.xx  key3: x.xx ...
```

```
//The result
Map<String, double[]> values = new HashMap<>();

//Remove the square brackets
input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);
//Separate every freq: x.xx mag: x.xx ...
String[] rows = input.split(", ");

for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i ++) {
  for (String s : rows[i].split("  ")) {
    //Split into "freq", "mag", etc. and the double value
    String[] keyVal = s.split(": ");
    String key = keyVal[0];
    String val = keyVal[1];
    //The first time, a new array has to be added
    if (i == 0) values.put(key, new double[rows.length]);
    //Parse the number and add it to the map
    values.get(key)[i] = Double.parseDouble(val);
  }
}
```

The output of this

```
for (var entry : values.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
}
```

is

```
mag: [8.22, 4.06, 0.92, 1.07, 18.54]
bw: [0.44, 0.41, 0.41, 0.38, 0.47]
snr: [2.47, 2.31, 2.24, 2.19, 2.15]
freq: [17.97, 9.96, 23.05, 12.99, 7.18]
med: [3.33, 1.76, 0.41, 0.49, 8.61]
```

assuming the input is defined like this (ignore the newlines, they're only for formatting's sake, because code doesn't wrap)

```
String input = 
"[freq: 17.97  mag: 8.22  bw: 0.44  snr: 2.47  med: 3.33, 
freq: 9.96  mag: 4.06  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.31  med: 1.76, 
freq: 23.05  mag: 0.92  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.24  med: 0.41, 
freq: 12.99  mag: 1.07  bw: 0.38  snr: 2.19  med: 0.49, 
freq: 7.18  mag: 18.54  bw: 0.47  snr: 2.15  med: 8.61]";
```

While the order of the keys isn't preserved (you could use a `LinkedHashMap` if you want that), the order of the numbers inside is.

---

Another way to do it with streams:

```
Map<String, List<Double>> res = Arrays
  .stream(input.split("[, ] "))
  .map(s -> s.split(": "))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0]))
  .entrySet().stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
      e -> e.getKey(),
      e -> e.getValue()
            .stream()
            .map(ns -> Double.parseDouble(ns[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Output

```
{mag=[8.22, 4.06, 0.92, 1.07, 18.54], 
bw=[0.44, 0.41, 0.41, 0.38, 0.47], 
snr=[2.47, 2.31, 2.24, 2.19, 2.15], 
freq=[17.97, 9.96, 23.05, 12.99, 7.18], 
med=[3.33, 1.76, 0.41, 0.49, 8.61]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map is your friend

```
String str = "[freq: 17.97  mag: 8.22  bw: 0.44  snr: 2.47  med: 3.33, freq: 9.96  mag: 4.06  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.31  med: 1.76," +
            " freq: 23.05  mag: 0.92  bw: 0.41  snr: 2.24  med: 0.41, freq: 12.99  mag: 1.07  bw: 0.38  snr: 2.19  med: 0.49, freq: 7.18 " +
            " mag: 18.54  bw: 0.47  snr: 2.15  med: 8.61]\n";
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(str.split("  |,")); // split into pair key : value
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    stringList.forEach(s1 -> {
                String[] splitedStrings = s1.split(": "); //split into key : value
                String key = splitedStrings[0].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]",""); // remove non alphanumeric from key, like {
                String value = splitedStrings[1];
                if (map.get(key) == null) {
                    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
                    values.add(value);
                    map.put(key, values);
                }else if (map.get(key) != null) {
                    map.get(key).add(value);
                }
            });
    System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{mag=[8.22, 4.06, 0.92, 1.07, 18.54], 
    bw=[0.44, 0.41, 0.41, 0.38, 0.47], 
    snr=[2.47, 2.31, 2.24, 2.19, 2.15], 
    freq=[17.97, 9.96, 23.05, 12.99, 7.18], 
    med=[3.33, 1.76, 0.41, 0.49, 8.61]
    ]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have been tinkering around with it and this works fairly well. I am not well versed in map, so to access specific values, which methods should I use? (get, etc.)

Comment: Just use map.get(keyHere) so map.get("mag") and it will return you the list of values. If you find my answer helpful please mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<Integer, Double[]>` to store your all arrays. First split by `,` then by . Cleaning and filtering has to be done and use of index to know where to put vales.

```
Map<Integer, Double[]> mapOfArrays = new HashMap<>();
String[] cleanAndSplitByComma = str.replace("]", "").split(",");
int arrayIndex = 0;
for (String line : cleanAndSplitByComma) {
    int partIndex = 0;
    for (String value : line.split(" ")) {
        if (!value.isBlank() && !value.contains(":")) {
            mapOfArrays.computeIfAbsent(partIndex,
                    c -> new Double[cleanAndSplitByComma.length]
            )[arrayIndex] = Double.valueOf(value);
            partIndex++;
        }
    }
    arrayIndex++;
}
```

After that you can get your array by index or print the whole map:

```
Double[] frequencyArray = mapOfArrays.get(0);
mapOfArrays.values().stream()
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[17.97, 9.96, 23.05, 12.99, 7.18]
[8.22, 4.06, 0.92, 1.07, 18.54]
[0.44, 0.41, 0.41, 0.38, 0.47]
[2.47, 2.31, 2.24, 2.19, 2.15]
[3.33, 1.76, 0.41, 0.49, 8.61]
```

Comment: Btw you can use a `double[]` instead of a `Double[]`, although I guess using the boxed version might be safer in case the OP needs to put it into another method later